# Communicating Python with android?

Tags: android, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on my Project but here arises a problem that I'm ready with my python script which controls raspberry pi 3 GPIO pins but I don't know how to interact my python script with Android. Someone told me that,it can be done using json as a bridge between these two languages but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: What hardware chanell you plan to use (USB, Wi-Fi, connect rasberry pi and android device to internet)?

Comment: I want it to be connected over wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to communicate android program and `something` is rest api.
To implement it on python side you can use [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Just take example from home page and put into `test.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    #PUT YOUR GPIO CODE HERE
    return "Hello World!"
```

then install flask(`pip install Flask`) and run application:
`FLASK_APP=test.py flask run -h 'IP_ADDRESS_OF_RASPERY_PI_IN_WIFI_NETWORK'`

after that connect android device to wifi, open browser and insert url
like flask suggest, something like `http://IP_ADDRESS_OF_RASPERY_PI_IN_WIFI_NETWORK:5000/` and you see that
you script handle this request.

After that you can take [retrofit java library](https://github.com/square/retrofit) and with it write
android application to control your rasberry pi.

Comment: EDIT: I created RESTapi using Flask but now how do I use retrofit library to develop an application ?

Comment: You can read here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792 , but it is for complex enough rest api. May be in your case, just give back to user html page with simple javacript and couple of buttons, and just use android default browser to control your hardware?

Comment: At last after several attempts it worked ! thanks mate